# At what point is the cube drawn?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm new to OpenGl and I was working on texturing. I want to draw one image on three sides and another image on other three sides of cube. I'm unable to do it. I want to know at what point in my code is cube being drawn on window?

This is my code:

```
#include "06_texturing.hpp"
#include "texture.hpp"

GLuint shaderProgram;
GLuint vbo[2], vao[2];
GLuint tex;

glm::mat4 rotation_matrix;
glm::mat4 projection_matrix;
glm::mat4 c_rotation_matrix;
glm::mat4 lookat_matrix;

glm::mat4 model_matrix;
glm::mat4 view_matrix;


glm::mat4 modelview_matrix;
glm::mat3 normal_matrix;

GLuint uModelViewMatrix;
GLuint viewMatrix;
GLuint normalMatrix;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------

//6 faces, 2 triangles/face, 3 vertices/triangle
const int num_vertices = 36;

glm::vec4 texCoordinates[8];
//Eight vertices in homogenous coordinates
glm::vec4 positions[8] = {
  glm::vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0)
};

glm::vec4 normals[8] = {
  glm::vec4(-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
   glm::vec4(-0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1.0)
};
//RGBA colors
glm::vec4 colors[8] = {
  glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec4(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
};

glm::vec2 t_coords[4] = {
  glm::vec2( 0.0, 0.0),
  glm::vec2( 0.0, 1.0),
  glm::vec2( 1.0, 0.0),
  glm::vec2( 1.0, 1.0)
};

glm::vec4 color(0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0);
glm::vec4 black(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
glm::vec4 white(0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
glm::vec4 red(1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
glm::vec4 yellow(0.8, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
glm::vec4 green(0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);
glm::vec4 blue(0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 1.0);

int tri_idx=0;
glm::vec4 v_positions[num_vertices];
glm::vec4 v_colors[num_vertices];
glm::vec4 v_normals[num_vertices];
glm::vec2 tex_coords[num_vertices];
// quad generates two triangles for each face and assigns colors to the vertices
void quad(int a, int b, int c, int d, glm::vec4 color)
{
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[a]; 
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[a]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[1];
  tri_idx++;
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[b];
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[b]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[0];
  tri_idx++;
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[c]; 
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[c]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[2];
  tri_idx++;
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[a]; 
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[a]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[1];
  tri_idx++;
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[c]; 
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[c]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[2];
  tri_idx++;
  v_colors[tri_idx] = color; v_positions[tri_idx] = positions[d]; 
  v_normals[tri_idx] = normals[d]; 
  tex_coords[tri_idx] = t_coords[3];
  tri_idx++;
 }

// generate 12 triangles: 36 vertices and 36 colors
void colorcube(void)
{
  quad( 1, 0, 3, 2, red);
  quad( 2, 3, 7, 6, green);
  quad( 3, 0, 4, 7, white);
  quad( 6, 5, 1, 2, yellow);
  quad( 4, 5, 6, 7, black);
  quad( 5, 4, 0, 1, blue);
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------

void initBuffersGL(void)
{

  // Load shaders and use the resulting shader program
  std::string vertex_shader_file("06_vshader.glsl");
  std::string fragment_shader_file("06_fshader.glsl");

  std::vector<GLuint> shaderList;
  shaderList.push_back(csX75::LoadShaderGL(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertex_shader_file));
  shaderList.push_back(csX75::LoadShaderGL(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragment_shader_file));

  shaderProgram = csX75::CreateProgramGL(shaderList);
  glUseProgram( shaderProgram );

  // getting the attributes from the shader program
  GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "vPosition" );
  GLuint vColor = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "vColor" ); 
  GLuint vNormal = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "vNormal" ); 
  GLuint texCoord = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "texCoord" ); 
  uModelViewMatrix = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "uModelViewMatrix");
  normalMatrix =  glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "normalMatrix");
  viewMatrix = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "viewMatrix");

  // Load Textures 
  GLuint tex=LoadTexture("images/all1.bmp",256,256);
  GLuint tex2=LoadTexture("images/another.bmp",256,256);


  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

  //Ask GL for two Vertex Attribute Objects (vao) , one for the sphere and one for the wireframe
  glGenVertexArrays (2, vao);
  //Ask GL for two Vertex Buffer Object (vbo)
  glGenBuffers (2, vbo);

  //Set 0 as the current array to be used by binding it
  glBindVertexArray (vao[0]);
  //Set 0 as the current buffer to be used by binding it
  glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);

  colorcube();

  //Copy the points into the current buffer
  glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (v_positions) + sizeof(tex_coords) + sizeof(v_normals), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(v_positions), v_positions );
  glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(v_positions), sizeof(tex_coords), tex_coords);
  glBufferSubData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tex_coords)+sizeof(v_positions), sizeof(v_normals), v_normals );
  // set up vertex array
  //Position
  glEnableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
  glVertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );
  //Textures
  glEnableVertexAttribArray( texCoord );
  glVertexAttribPointer( texCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(v_positions)) );

  //Normal
  glEnableVertexAttribArray( vNormal );
  glVertexAttribPointer( vNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(v_positions)+sizeof(tex_coords)) );




}

void renderGL(void)
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(xrot), glm::vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(rotation_matrix, glm::radians(yrot), glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
  rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(rotation_matrix, glm::radians(zrot), glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));
  model_matrix = rotation_matrix;

  //Creating the lookat and the up vectors for the camera
  c_rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(c_xrot), glm::vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f));
  c_rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(c_rotation_matrix, glm::radians(c_yrot), glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
  c_rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(c_rotation_matrix, glm::radians(c_zrot), glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f));

  glm::vec4 c_pos = glm::vec4(c_xpos,c_ypos,c_zpos, 1.0)*c_rotation_matrix;
  glm::vec4 c_up = glm::vec4(c_up_x,c_up_y,c_up_z, 1.0)*c_rotation_matrix;
  //Creating the lookat matrix
  lookat_matrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(c_pos),glm::vec3(0.0),glm::vec3(c_up));

  //creating the projection matrix

  projection_matrix = glm::frustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0);

  view_matrix = projection_matrix*lookat_matrix;

  glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));

 // Draw the sphere
  modelview_matrix = view_matrix*model_matrix;
  glUniformMatrix4fv(uModelViewMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelview_matrix));
  normal_matrix = glm::transpose (glm::inverse(glm::mat3(modelview_matrix)));
  glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(normal_matrix));
  //  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  glBindVertexArray (vao[0]);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  //! The pointer to the GLFW window
  GLFWwindow* window;

  //! Setting up the GLFW Error callback
  glfwSetErrorCallback(csX75::error_callback);

  //! Initialize GLFW
  if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;
  //We want OpenGL 4.0
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); 
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  //This is for MacOSX - can be omitted otherwise
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); 
  //We don't want the old OpenGL 
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); 

  //! Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
  window = glfwCreateWindow(512, 512, "CS475/CS675 Tutorial 6: Texturing a cube", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window)
    {
      glfwTerminate();
      return -1;
    }

  //! Make the window's context current 
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  //Initialize GLEW
  //Turn this on to get Shader based OpenGL
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  GLenum err = glewInit();
  if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
      //Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong.
      std::cerr<<"GLEW Init Failed : %s"<<std::endl;
    }
  //Keyboard Callback
  glfwSetKeyCallback(window, csX75::key_callback);
  //Framebuffer resize callback
  glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, csX75::framebuffer_size_callback);

  // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
  glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

  //Initialize GL state
  csX75::initGL();
  initBuffersGL();

  // Loop until the user closes the window
  while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0)
    {

      // Render here
      renderGL();

      // Swap front and back buffers
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);

      // Poll for and process events
      glfwPollEvents();
    }

  glfwTerminate();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to change in it to render different images on different sides.

Comment: The draw call is `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, num_vertices)`. But this is not where you would change the texture. You have to upload an appropriate texture and texture coordinates before that (happens in `initBuffersGL()`).

Comment: The IMHO most simple way to render different images on different sides (of one mesh) is to combine the two images into one texture. Your texture coordinates can be set accordingly to address only the one or other half. E.g. a front side with (-.5, -.5, -.5), (+.5, -.5, -.5), (+.5, -.5, +.5), (-.5, -.5, +.5) may have the corresponding texture coordinates (.0, .0), (.5, .0), (.5, 1.), (.0, 1.) covering only the left half of image. This may look like non-square but in combination with a combined image of e.g. 512 x 256 it results in square texels again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use 2 completely different textures, in the fragment shader, then you have to bind the textures to 2 different texture units. The texture unit can be set by [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml):

```
GLuint tex=LoadTexture("images/all1.bmp",256,256);
GLuint tex2=LoadTexture("images/another.bmp",256,256);

int unit_tex0 = 0; // texture unit 0 and binding point 0
int unit_tex1 = 1; // texture unit 1 and binding point 1

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + unit_tex0 );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + unit_tex1 );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
```

Further you have to declare 2 texture samplers in the fragment shader. The texture samplers have to be associated to the texture units. Since GLSL version 4.2 this can be done in the fragment shader by specifying [binding points](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Binding_points):

```
#version 420

layout (binding = 0) uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D u_texture1;
```

Alternatively you can assign the texture unit index, to the texture sampler uniform by [`glUniform1i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml):

```
uniform sampler2D u_texture0;
uniform sampler2D u_texture1;
```

```
GLuint location_tex0 = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "u_texture0" ); 
GLuint location_tex1 = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "u_texture1" ); 

glUniform1i( location_tex0, unit_tex0 );
glUniform1i( location_tex1, unit_tex1 );
```

To distinguish between the sides of the cubes, you can use the built in vertex shader variable [`gl_VertexID`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Other_inputs).
Create a [`flat`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers) `out` variable of type `int` in the vertex shader and pass the vertex id to the fragment shader:

```
flat out int vertex_id;

void main()
{
    .....

    vertex_id = gl_VertexID;

    .....
}
```

In the fragment shader yo can decide which texture you want to use by the id corresponding to the vertex coordinate. Note, you have 36 coordinates, the first 3 sides have the ids form 0 to 17 and the other the ids form 18 to 35:

```
flat in int vertex_id;

void main()
{
    .....

    if ( vertex_id < 18 )
       fragColor = texture(u_texture0, vertUV);
    else
       fragColor = texture(u_texture1, vertUV);

    .....
}
```

Comment: That's _the_ alternative to _combine two images in one texture_. Though, I saw 3d models in the web where everything dedicated for textures was combined in one image. This let me think it was probably for different reasons... (e.g. minimizing image loading, optimal use of power 2 texture dimensions, reducing state changes, or whatever).

Comment: @Scheff Of course it would be possible to use a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` in this case, because the images have the same resolution of 256x256. But the function `LoadTexture` seems to generate a texture object. In the question there are used 2 independent texture objects, so I decided to use them in my answer.

Comment: :-) I didn't want to combine the textures - just combine the images and load them as one texture... (I even didn't think about `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` - yet another nice idea.)